# ValueError exception not working in python

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm trying to make a simple program that will calculate the area of a circle when I input the radius. When I input a number it works, but when I input something else I'd like it to say "That's not a number" and let me try again instead of giving me an error.

I can't figure out why this is not working.

```
from math import pi

def get_area(r):
    area = pi * (r**2)
    print "A= %d" % area

def is_number(number):
    try:
        float(number)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

loop = True
while loop == True:
    radius = input("Enter circle radius:")
    if is_number(radius) == True:
        get_area(radius)
        loop = False
    else:
        print "That's not a number!"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't input a number, the error is thrown by `input` itself which is not in the scope of your `try/except`. You can simply discard the `is_number` function altogether which is quite redundant and put the `print` statement in the `except` block:

```
try:
    radius = input("Enter circle radius:")
except (ValueError, NameError):
    print "That's not a number!"
get_area(radius)
```

Answer (score 0):

`radius` is still a string,

replace

```
 get_area(radius)
```

with

```
get_area(float(radius))
```

You also have to replace `input` with `raw_input` since you're using Python 2

Answer (score 0):

```
in= 0
while True:
  try:
     in= int(input("Enter something: "))       
  except ValueError:
     print("Not an integer!")
     continue
  else:
     print("Yes an integer!")
     break
```